# Weak convergence of measures and Fourier Transform

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $\psi_0\in C^2_c(\mathbb{R})$ be a real function such that supp$(\psi_0)=[0,1]$, $\psi_0>0$ in $(0,1)$ **and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi_0=1$**. For $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$, let $G_k:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be an even, $1-$periodic and $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ function such that $||G_k||_{L^{\infty}}<\infty$. ($G_k$ is constructed in a particular way, but I think the details are irrelevant in this question).

Let $\mu_k(A)=\int_A\psi G_k d\lambda^1$ be a sequence of finite Borel measures ($\lambda^1$ is the Lebesgue measure on the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$). So the Fourier transform of the measures are $\widehat{\mu_k}(w)=\widehat{\psi_0G_k}(w)$.

Suppose the sequence $\{\widehat{\mu_k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the supremum norm, then

There exists a finite measure $\mu_\alpha$ such that $\mu_k\xrightarrow{w}\mu_\alpha$ (weak convergence).

My question is, why does there exist such $\mu_\alpha$?

My reasoning:

Given that $\{\widehat{\mu_k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the supremum norm, then there exists a function $h$ such that $\{\widehat{\mu_k}\}\to h$ uniformly. I am aware of the Lévy's Continuity Theorem, but in this case it may happen that $\sup_k\{\mu_k(\mathbb{R})\}=\infty$ and I couldn't find a generalization for that case.

Moreover, I can't see that $h\in L^1$ (in general it isn't true but it could be in this case due to the properties of $\psi_0$ and $G_k$).

Any help is highly appreciated. Kind regards.

EDIT: Forgot to state that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi_0=1$.